# AngularJS : How to encode decode JSON data in Services

Tags: angularjs, cakephp

I have used CakePHP + AngularJS for the application

I have below code in Sevices file

```
test.factory('Dashboard', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        userDirectory: function (){
            return $http.get(hostName + 'dashboards/userDirectory.json');
        }
    }
});
```

The above code calls dashboards's controllers userDirectory function and return JSON data this is how it's work.

Some one raised one issue, When he hit url "**http://hostname/dashboards/userDirectory.json**" he can see the response data in browser and that is not authenticated. Is there any way through which I can secure it.

By any encoding/decoding or What you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Decode/encode doesn't make any sense here if the client can decode it the user can get the data as well.
- Just send data the user is allowed to see and use, even if he is authorized for that request, remove everything else that is not needed.
- Use a JWT token to authorize them

  - https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth
  - http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/
  - http://florian-kraemer.net/2014/07/cakephp-and-token-based-auth-with-angular-js/